# Chrome's captureVisibleTab without extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I know, that you can do screenshot of website in chrome extensions wit this:
`chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, {format: 'png'}, capturedImage);`

But is this possible with just in javascript? I tried js plugin html2canvas, but these screenshots are terrible. My website is fulled with transitions/animations, 3D transforms... And that html2canvas is unable to make screenshot of that.

But I found chrome extension, which makes screenshot of website and that extension has made perfect job. Then I looked into extension's script and found that function `captureVisibleTab`.

Hope you know, what's my point. Do you know, how can I access to `chrome.tabs`? Or some other way, to use chrome's capture system?

**EDIT:**
To compare original website and screenshot from html2canvas:

Original website:
[image: Original website]

HTML2Canvas screenshot:
[image: HTML2Canvas screenshot]

Comment: Why do you need to do it without an extension, anyway?

Comment: I'm doing eye dropper, so user on my website can use eye dropper to pick any color from website and use it in the text editor. Best way to do eye dropper, is capture screen, make overlay with image and then get user clicks position. I already made whole plugin working like it would, only these screenshots (capture of screen) are terrible comparing to the original website.

Comment: But why can't you use an extension to take the screenshot?

Comment: Because my **users** don't have this extension.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't.

It's a highly privileged API, and only an extension which was explicitly granted an extremely high access permission `"<all_urls>"` [can use it](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-captureVisibleTab).

Comment: Ew, that's bad. Thanks for answer anyway.